# Cucumber - Selenium - Browser Instance is not closing after a failed scenario

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, gradle, cucumber

I'm using Selenium with Cucumber along with Gradle and TestNG. The same scenario runs for multiple parameters (Examples). Issue I'm facing is that for the first assertion success, browser (driver) closes. But for subsequent assertions failures, browser (driver) does not close, instead a new browser instance is launched for next set of values.

### My Feature file

```
Feature: Using Contact Form
 To test the functionality of contact form

  Scenario Outline: Filling contact form
   Given I am on Home Page of "http://room5.trivago.com/contact/"
   And Dismiss cookies popup
   When I enter message as "<message>"
   And I enter full name as "<fullname>"
   And I enter email as "<email>"
   And I click on Submit button
   Then I see success message
   Examples:
   |message|fullname|email|
   |just some gibberish message|Ashish Deshmukh|ashish@deshmukh.com|
   | |Ashish Deshmukh|ashish@deshmukh.com|
   |just some givverish message| |ashish@deshmukh.com|
   |just some gibberish message|Ashish Deshmukh| |
```

### My StepDefination file

```
package stepDef;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import pageObjectModels.ContactPageObjectModel;
import pageObjectModels.CookiesNoticePageObjectModel;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Contact_Form extends Test_Base{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static ContactPageObjectModel objContact;
    public static CookiesNoticePageObjectModel objCookies;
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware");

    @Given("^I am on Home Page of \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_am_on_Home_Page_of(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium Webdriver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(arg1);
        objContact = new ContactPageObjectModel(driver);
        objCookies = new CookiesNoticePageObjectModel(driver);
    }

    @Given("^Dismiss cookies popup$")
    public void dismiss_cookies_popup() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        objCookies.acceptCookies();
    }

    @When("^I enter message as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_enter_message_as(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        objContact.enterMessage(arg1);
    }

    @When("^I enter full name as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_enter_full_name_as(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        objContact.enterFullName(arg1);
    }

    @When("^I enter email as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_enter_email_as(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        objContact.enterEmail(arg1);
    }

    @When("^I click on Submit button$")
    public void i_click_on_Submit_button() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        objContact.clickSubmit();
    }

    @Then("^I see success message$")
    public void i_see_success_message() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        String status = objContact.getSuccessStatus();
        Assert.assertEquals(status, "Success");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

### My build.gradle to run the test

```
group 'com.seleniumtestcucumber.mytest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}


task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'stepDef', 'src/test/java']
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.44.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.4.0'
    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.1.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-testng', version: '1.2.5'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.5'

}
```

### Console Log

```
Feature: Using Contact Form
  To test the functionality of contact form

  Scenario Outline: Filling contact form                           # features/Contact_Form.feature:5
    Given I am on Home Page of "http://room5.trivago.com/contact/"
    And Dismiss cookies popup
    When I enter message as "<message>"
    And I enter full name as "<fullname>"
    And I enter email as "<email>"
    And I click on Submit button
    Then I see success message

    Examples: 
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233) on port 42643
Only local connections are allowed.
Aug 10, 2017 4:21:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Accepted cookies notice.
Entered message: just some gibberish message
Entered name: Ashish Deshmukh
Entered email: ashish@deshmukh.com
Clicked on Submit button.
Success

  Scenario Outline: Filling contact form                           # features/Contact_Form.feature:15
    Given I am on Home Page of "http://room5.trivago.com/contact/" # Contact_Form.i_am_on_Home_Page_of(String)
    And Dismiss cookies popup                                      # Contact_Form.dismiss_cookies_popup()
    When I enter message as "just some gibberish message"          # Contact_Form.i_enter_message_as(String)
    And I enter full name as "Ashish Deshmukh"                     # Contact_Form.i_enter_full_name_as(String)
    And I enter email as "ashish@deshmukh.com"                     # Contact_Form.i_enter_email_as(String)
    And I click on Submit button                                   # Contact_Form.i_click_on_Submit_button()
    Then I see success message                                     # Contact_Form.i_see_success_message()
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233) on port 11801
Only local connections are allowed.
Aug 10, 2017 4:21:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Accepted cookies notice.
Entered message: 
Entered name: Ashish Deshmukh
Entered email: ashish@deshmukh.com
Clicked on Submit button.
Error

  Scenario Outline: Filling contact form                           # features/Contact_Form.feature:16
    Given I am on Home Page of "http://room5.trivago.com/contact/" # Contact_Form.i_am_on_Home_Page_of(String)
    And Dismiss cookies popup                                      # Contact_Form.dismiss_cookies_popup()
    When I enter message as ""                                     # Contact_Form.i_enter_message_as(String)
    And I enter full name as "Ashish Deshmukh"                     # Contact_Form.i_enter_full_name_as(String)
    And I enter email as "ashish@deshmukh.com"                     # Contact_Form.i_enter_email_as(String)
    And I click on Submit button                                   # Contact_Form.i_click_on_Submit_button()
    Then I see success message                                     # Contact_Form.i_see_success_message()
      java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Success] but found [Error]
        at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
        at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:513)
        at org.testng.Assert.assertEqualsImpl(Assert.java:135)
        at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:116)
        at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:190)
        at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:200)
        at stepDef.Contact_Form.i_see_success_message(Contact_Form.java:72)
        at ✽.Then I see success message(features/Contact_Form.feature:12)

Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233) on port 22809
Only local connections are allowed.
Aug 10, 2017 4:22:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Kindly suggest how to over come this. Is there a way I can use @BeforeTest @AfterTest in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about **cucumber hooks** in details.

For your specific problem, you can use `@Afte`r and `@Before`. This works for Junit Runner, never tested with TestNG but should work I guess as hooks are part of Cucumber and not JUnit/TestNG.

```
import cucumber.annotation.After;
import cucumber.annotation.Before;

@Before
public void beforeScenario() 
{
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium Webdriver/chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@After
public void afterScenario() 
{
     driver.quit()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked for TestNG as well.